# In secondviewcontroller UIBarbuttonItem not visible for swrevealviewcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, swrevealviewcontroller

Im working with SWRevealViewController, it's working properly. But UIBarButtonItem image not visible from second view controller onwards. For first one it's working fine. Im using storyboard segue's from tableviewcells.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if([segue isKindOfClass:[SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController class] ]){

    UIViewController *dvc = [segue destinationViewController];

    UINavigationController *navCtrl = (UINavigationController *) self.revealViewController.frontViewController;

    [navCtrl setViewControllers:@[dvc] animated:NO];

    [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition:FrontViewPositionLeft animated:YES];
}

}
```

Im using above code in `SideMenuViewController` class.

Im using below code only in `FrontViewController` `viewDidLoad`.

```
UILabel* lbNavTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,40,320,40)];
lbNavTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
lbNavTitle.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Hello World!",@"");
self.navigationItem.titleView = lbNavTitle;


self.barButton.target = self.revealViewController;
self.barButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First drag UIViewController and drag Navigation Item from object library.

If it's navigation bar not visible, click on UIViewController and go to Simulated metrics in attributes inspector, then select Translucent NavigationBar option in Top Bar.

[image]

Now the Navigation Item will be visible on ViewController. Then drag UIBarButtonItem and if you want, add image to this bar button item....